# Best way to store a dictionary (of words) into Google Cloud Datastore

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, key-value-store

I was wondering what the most optimal way would be to store a large list of dictionary words such as https://github.com/dwyl/english-words in the google cloud datastore (using Google App Engine/Java Standard), for querying later, query input is the full word.

I need only check the word is valid, i.e. is on the list.

I thought I could use the first couple of characters in each word as the key for an entity, and store a HashSet of all the words that begin with those characters as the value in that particular entity.

then later I check the first couple of characters of the word I'm searching for and look at that key only.

I get the feeling there's a better way to do this. but I've been googling this a lot, to no avail.

any ideas would be very much appreciated !

Comment: Have you considered using the search index, rather than the datastore?

Comment: sorry about delay, I am going to look into that as an option today

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1:**

Store it in memory and not in the datastore.  A list of words is quite small in the grand scheme of things.

You can store the data alongside your code.  In one of your modules, read the data from the file into whatever data structure works for you.  This operation will only be performed when an instance is spun up so it won't be a drag on your response times.

Note that you can't write to disk in GAE but you can read from disk.

**Option 2:**

Store it in a single entity with a JSON property or a Pickle Property or even a repeated string property.  You can use compression to make sure you don't exceed the 1MB entity size.

If you are using Python NDB, the automatic caching will make this quite efficient.

Comment: Sorry about the delay. I'm using Java for this project so NDB is not an option (more's the pity). loading from a text file to memory each time I start the project could be quite slow? The words database is 4MB uncompressed, was considering build a binary search tree object and storing it in google cloud storage but I'm a bit unsure about that.

Comment: @TheDavil, that seems excessively big for a word list.  You may want to find a smaller one.  I would think that loading the word list would take less than a second.  You can also split the word list across 2-3 entities if you need to, and you can use memcache with Java as well.